# Sourcing files in ZSH doesn't work

Tags: zsh, newlines

Because my .zshrc got quite big I chose to just source other files, but I encounter some errors after logging in to ssh now:

```
/home/rob1nn/.r_inc/exports:13: parse error near `\n'
/home/rob1nn/.r_inc/functions:39: parse error near `in^M'
/home/rob1nn/.r_inc/modules:5: command not found: compinit^M
/home/rob1nn/.r_inc/modules:6: command not found: promptinit^M
/home/rob1nn/.r_inc/modules:7: command not found: zsh-mime-setup
/home/rob1nn/.r_inc/optins:setopt:4: no such option: SHARE_HISTORY^M
/home/rob1nn/.r_inc/optins:setopt:5: no such option: RM_STAR_WAIT^M
/home/rob1nn/.r_inc/optins:setopt:6: no such option: ZLE^M
/home/rob1nn/.r_inc/optins:setopt:7: no such option: NO_FLOW_CONTROL^M
/home/rob1nn/.r_inc/optins:setopt:8: no such option: NO_BEEP^M
/home/rob1nn/.r_inc/startscreen:4: command not found: clear^M
```

I sourced the files using **source ~/.r_inc/functions** for example but it doesn't load any of them

Comment: Do you have these `^M` control characters in the files?

Comment: No, _"modules"_ for example looks like [this](http://puu.sh/bOCMV/cbb3e731c4.png)

Comment: Could you upload one of the files to a pastebin site instead? For instance `curl -F "sprunge=@$HOME/.r_inc/modules" sprunge.us` to upload `~/.r_inc/modules` directly to sprunge.us

Comment: There you go @kyrias [sprunge.us](http://sprunge.us/FAWE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You saved the files being sourced with DOS line endings (CRLF).  Your editor automatically recognizes this and doesn't show the ^M characters, but they're still there.  (It probably has some other indicator that the file uses DOS line endings.)

You need to remove the CR characters.  One way is this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r//' /home/rob1nn/.r_inc/*
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Is there any way to prevent that from happening in the future or should i just run this command after editing the files?

Comment: @Rob1NN, you should ask another question about how you managed to save a file in DOS format.  Give details of the editor you used and the exact process by which you split your .zshrc into separate files.

Comment: @Rob1NN, your editor will probably notice that the files are now LF-only and preserve that, but I can't guarantee it since I don't know what editor you're using.

Comment: I used notepad++ on my windows pc

Comment: @Rob1NN, there's your problem.  Windows editors tend to create files with Windows line endings (CRLF).  Notepad++ can create Unix-style files (LF), but it's not the default.